# Receiving a Task<T> from another process on same machine

Tags: c#, task

I have two internal processes which I use to upload long sdos strings to an API. Process 1 reads these from another stream. Process 1 (client) sends strings to process 2 (server) via a `[ServiceContract]` and a `[MessageContract]`. Process 2 then sends this to an API which in turn processes the sdos and uploads to a server.

```
[MessageContract]
public class CallRequestMessage
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string Sdos;
    [MessageHeader]
    public int ArrayLength;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream SdosStream;
}

[MessageContract]
public class CallResponseMessage
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public Task<ResultCode> Task;
}
```

Since the bulk of the time processing the string is in the API, I want to try and return a `Task<ResultCode>` from my server that will get a result from the API once the processing has concluded. Then my threads can work on client-side processing (in this case, reading the sdos strings from a stream input).

My problem is that the tasks returned to the client seem to be different to the ones that I create on the server. On the server I have the code

```
task = Task<ResultCode>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ResultCode res;
    lock (SyncObject)
        res = upload(/* input */)
    return res;
});

// ...other code

return new CallResponseMessage { Task = task };
```

where `upload` is a method in the API, accessed by process 2 by using a `[DllImportAttribute]`.

Using logs I have seen that the task *does* complete on the server (all sdos are uploaded), however on the client side, all tasks appear to not have started, and so retrieving the results is not possible directly.

An alternative approach that I thought of would be to return nothing from the server, and add a separate method that retrospectively goes to the server, awaits the tasks, and returns an aggregated result. I would like to try and get the task back directly, though, as this implementation may be a model for future services in my projects.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I would have zero expectation of a `Task[<T>]` working between processes, and likewise I would have zero expectation of it working over WCF.... I don't think this is the right way to solve the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no `Task` instances across process boundaries. The server's task is the `Task` that sends the data to the client. The client task is the task that receives the data. If you use the asnyc methods on the auto-generated WCF clients, by default, WCF will not stream the data from server to client, so your normal flow will be:

*Start client task -> Send request -> Start server task -> End server task -> Send response -> End client task*

In order for the server tasks to be performed asynchronously, you can design your service methods with the task asynchronous pattern (TAP). This example is from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/synchronous-and-asynchronous-operations):

```
public class SampleService:ISampleService   
{   
   // ...  
   public async Task<string> SampleMethodTaskAsync(string msg)   
   {   
      return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>   
      {   
         return msg;   
      });   
   }  
   // ...  
}
```

The benefits of tasks on client and server is not so much that the client can receive while the server sends the data, but to allow the server to process more incoming requests while other requests are waiting for long running operations (e.g. data access) and the client to do something useful while the data is received.

Your options are:

**Use seperate asynchronous server and client operations**

Unless you are transferring large amounts of data and performance is critical, there is nothing wrong with the situation. You can still use tasks for async programming. However, your approach of returning a task won't work. Use the described combination of async service methods and the auto-generated async client methods. You will essentially achieve the same result, which is that both, client and server will perform the operation asynchronously.

**Stream the data**

If you *must* start processing on the client while the server is sending the data (which only brings you a *practical* benefit for large amounts of data), you can stream the data from the server. This issue is too large to cover here, but a good point to start is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming).